# creating bundle in symfony in terminal

Tags: php, symfony

i want to create a bundle in my symfony project via

```
php bin/console generate:bundle
```

but it errors me in the terminal:

> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException] The file
>   "../../src/AppBundle" does not exist (in:
>   C:\wamp64\www\exp\app/config) in
>   C:\wamp64\www\exp\app/config\services.yml (which is being imported
>   from "C:\wam p64\www\exp\app/config\config.yml").
>
> [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLocatorFileNotFoundException] 
>   The file "../../src/AppBundle" does not exist (in:
>   C:\wamp64\www\exp\app/config).

Comment: Show your `config.yml` and must sure that `AppKernel.php` is present at root folder bcoz the Bundle is register in that at the time of creation...

Answer (score 0):

You might have deleted **AppBundle** from **src** folder (or test folder) manually which is the major reason for getting this error.

Browse **app\config\config.yml** , **app\AppKernel.php** and **app\config\routing.yml** and remove the referring to AppBundle.

Once done Please clear the cache and re-run the project.